# Center Fixed Element in TailwindCSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a flash message that appears when a page is loaded on successful auth and I'm trying to figure out how I can center it horizontally on any device. I am using the TailwindCSS to adjust the placement of the div and have tried `fixed` and `absolute` to make sure it appears above my content, but using an attribute like `left:50%` moves it too far over and `margin:auto` doesn't center this element. Is there a better approach to what I am trying to do? Is it possible to do with TailwindCSS or will I have to write some CSS for this?

[image: Screenshot]

**Code:**

```
<div>
    <div className="mx-auto sm:w-3/4 md:w-2/4 absolute" id="signin-success-message">
        <div className="bg-green-200 px-6 py-4 my-4 rounded-md text-lg flex items-center w-full">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" className="text-green-600 w-10 h-10 sm:w-5 sm:h-5 mr-3">
                <path fill="currentColor" d="M12,0A12,12,0,1,0,24,12,12.014,12.014,0,0,0,12,0Zm6.927,8.2-6.845,9.289a1.011,1.011,0,0,1-1.43.188L5.764,13.769a1,1,0,1,1,1.25-1.562l4.076,3.261,6.227-8.451A1,1,0,1,1,18.927,8.2Z"></path>
            </svg>
            <span class="text-green-800">{ body ? body : '' }</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use [`inset-x-0`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left) with `mx-auto`

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="mx-auto sm:w-3/4 md:w-2/4 fixed inset-x-0 top-10" id="signin-success-message">
  <div class="bg-green-200 px-6 py-4 my-4 rounded-md text-lg flex items-center w-full">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="text-green-600 w-10 h-10 sm:w-5 sm:h-5 mr-3">
                <path fill="currentColor" d="M12,0A12,12,0,1,0,24,12,12.014,12.014,0,0,0,12,0Zm6.927,8.2-6.845,9.289a1.011,1.011,0,0,1-1.43.188L5.764,13.769a1,1,0,1,1,1.25-1.562l4.076,3.261,6.227-8.451A1,1,0,1,1,18.927,8.2Z"></path>
            </svg>
    <span class="text-green-800">{ body ? body : '' }</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

To have vertical centring:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="mx-auto sm:w-3/4 md:w-2/4 fixed inset-0 flex items-center" id="signin-success-message">
  <div class="bg-green-200 px-6 py-4 rounded-md text-lg flex items-center w-full">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="text-green-600 w-10 h-10 sm:w-5 sm:h-5 mr-3">
                <path fill="currentColor" d="M12,0A12,12,0,1,0,24,12,12.014,12.014,0,0,0,12,0Zm6.927,8.2-6.845,9.289a1.011,1.011,0,0,1-1.43.188L5.764,13.769a1,1,0,1,1,1.25-1.562l4.076,3.261,6.227-8.451A1,1,0,1,1,18.927,8.2Z"></path>
            </svg>
    <span class="text-green-800">{ body ? body : '' }</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about centering vertically?

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked like this (div is centered both vertically and horizontally). Also I wanted the modal content to scroll if the content was longer than the div's height:

```
<div
  v-if="isModalOpen"
  class="fixed z-20 h-3/4 w-1/2 m-auto inset-x-0 inset-y-0 p-4 bg-white rounded-sm overflow-y-scroll"
>
  <button @click.prevent="closeModal">Close me</button>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut voluptas
  omnis nemo quas minima quam, repudiandae doloremque. Sunt magnam officia
  voluptatibus nostrum eligendi dignissimos minima itaque, praesentium
  corrupti obcaecati quas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
  adipisicing elit. At harum id magni consequuntur ratione aperiam! Quasi
  animi sunt molestiae eos a voluptatem exercitationem voluptate quo,
  consectetur fugit tempore impedit qui! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea quae dolor maiores animi dolores deleniti
  laborum quis molestias nulla, reprehenderit eos odio recusandae
  consectetur velit saepe explicabo quibusdam quidem? Corrupti.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use    inset-x-0 max-w-max mx-auto

if you don't have element full wide....