# How to keep the margins on the left and right side adjusted but the same? TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

To start I'm sure someone had answered something very similar to what I am asking but I can't find a specific resource and multiple different approaches have had differing results that are all unsatisfactory.  Originally I just fixed my dive exactly in the center of the screen via `mx-[40%] mt-[10%]' this works okay for my exact screen size but any zooming or viewport manipulation suddenly makes all the aspect ratios very odd and you can tell it's off.

The second thing I tried to do was just fix the aspect via like `aspect-[4/3]` then just have it be centered with like flex box or something but no values for aspect actually correctly shaped the dive and it would always extend completely across the screen.

Lastly I looked around for someone with a similar problem as me on stack overflow but their solution didn't work for me despite it seeming to be my exact problem.  So I yoinked this: [Center Fixed Element in TailwindCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65719655/center-fixed-element-in-tailwindcss) and tried some variations with the wisdom of setting min widths and heights (not sure what inset does still) but the issue with this approach is twofold:

1. It only looks good for specific screen sizes (it's not always centered)
2. When zooming in and out with my mouse on the left border of the login div I can see the right border moving and expanding as more space becomes available but the left border is always fixed.  This has the effect of rescaling the login div but it quickly eats all the margin at the right and top of the screen until it looks like this:
   [image: Fucked margins]

But this is how it looks on a slightly non-standard resolution at 100% Still not completely center. [image: Still not centered]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Tailwind, you have two options:

**If the element you want to center is absolute or fixed:**
Apply the following classNames: `top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2`. But make sure to set `relative` positioning to the parent you want it to be centered from.

Else, you can simply surround your element by a `<div>` that would be a flexbox, taking the full-width, and justify-center the elements, like that:

`<div className="flex justify-center w-full">Centered Element</div>`

You can see working example on my Tailwind Playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/ddsnarMIob

Comment: I would say this got me 99% of the way there thank you I guess the part I was missing was just combining flex and a width, maybe you could describe to me a little more what "w-full" is doing here?  The only thing this doesn't do is center it vertically without doing your fixed way of centering (I don't want it to be fixed flex just wasn't working how I wanted it to). So I just added a %margin on top which passes my smell check for ui

Comment: No problem. w-full makes sure that the element takes the whole width. As you want to center horizontally, if the div would takes 50%, then it'd be centered at 25% of the page. So we make sure it takes 100% (full) width.  For vertical, just add items-center

Comment: @Jigen "just add items-center" in this case isn't enough. You also have to add "min-h-screen" to get height to vertical center elements.

Comment: Assuming that he has a white background'd container that takes the whole screen in the screenshot, it isn't. But, in the case he has no space allowed, then yes.